# How much heat can a heat sensor on a video card handle?

Tags: overheating, sensors

I have some troubles with my XFX HD5770 (video card), the head sensors on my video card are broken but I'm out of warranty. I need to prove to the reseller that I didn't damage the head sensors by for example to much heat. If I can do that, then I will get extra warranty that will cover these problems.

I guess that the head sensors on the video card can handle much heat, but I can't find how much head they can handle. I want to prove to them that if the sensors are damaged by to much head, that it is imposable that the rest of the video card still operates normaly.

So what kind of head sensors are used on modern video cards, and how much heat can they handle?

Comment: They should be able to handle a lot more heat than the GPU itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT realy depends on what type of sensor your video card is using.
some of them go up to 125° C / 150° C other 280° C and above

regards